# Docusign Tabs and signers in multiple composite templates

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Hi guys I'm working to build a document based on several composite templates and I'm having problems at the time to populate the data in the document...

This is my use case:

I'll have 4 signers and 7 sections(each of these are separated composite templates)

- the signer 1 will sign section 1,2,4,6 with different tabs values
- the signers 2 and 3 will sign the sections 1,3,5(a new copy for each one so I create a composite for each signer)
- the signer 4 signs the sections 6 and 7

for each template that needs to be signed for more than one person, I create a custom template and a Signer object for each one, like this

```
documentsSequence.incrementAndGet();
CompositeTemplate templateS6CompositeTemplate = new CompositeTemplate();
templateS6CompositeTemplate.setCompositeTemplateId(documentsSequence.toString());

Recipients recipientsS6 = new Recipients();
recipientsS6.signers(signer);

ServerTemplate templateS6ServerTemplate = new ServerTemplate();
templateS6ServerTemplate.setSequence("1");
templateS6ServerTemplate.setTemplateId(templateS6);

InlineTemplate templateS6InlineTemplate = new InlineTemplate();
templateS6InlineTemplate.setSequence("2");
templateS6InlineTemplate.setRecipients(recipientsS6);

templateS6CompositeTemplate.addServerTemplatesItem(templateS6ServerTemplate);
templateS6CompositeTemplate.addInlineTemplatesItem(templateS6InlineTemplate);
envelopeDefinition.addCompositeTemplatesItem(templateS6CompositeTemplate);
```

the problem appears when I try to populate the data bc if I create a Signer for each section that I need to sign I get from the DocuSign side more than 4 signers bc I repeat the signer for some sections so for DocuSign are different(makes sense bc I create a new Signer obj for each one) and I set the Tabs for each one and I get all the document populated in the right way but at the signing time, I have more than the 4 real signers.

If I use the same signer object the tabs are overridden and I just populate the last tabs that were set for that signer

so IDK how to set the Tabs and Signers on each composite template when I'll have the same signer in different composites templates.

The tech stack that I use is Java and DocuSign api v3.3.0

Could you help me with this?

envelope json https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kK9V869m-2NXOgNLz13HsKT0IfQxZEG0/view?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include the [API log](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus) of your request. Edit out any private data.

Comment: @LarryK I have added the json file if that help

Comment: Unfortunately you added an rtf file of a non- pretty json,--not so helpful. Please use an online pretty print web site and then edit (update) your question to include the json

Comment: I have updated the file

Comment: @LarryK also I made these two tests but they doesn't work https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mGZLsjbYhr6Rj2fHQ6z-pc7-R46FWCOQ?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the query parameter `merge_roles_on_draft` to `true`

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work, I have posted the link of the envelopeDefinition in json format